# View遷移時に画像が渡せません。

Tags: swift, swift3

下記のコードでsignal SIGABRTのエラーが出てしまいます。

*view controller1*

```
@IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var image2: UIImageView!

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc2 = segue.destination as! ViewController2
    vc2.image3 = self.image1.image
    vc2.image4 = self.image2.image
}
```

*view controller2 (vc2)*

```
@IBOutlet weak var image21: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var image22: UIImageView!

var image3: UIImage?
var image4: UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.image21.image = image3
    self.image22.image = image4
}
```

Comment: あなたが現在挙げられている情報だけで原因を推測するのは極めて困難です。少なくとも、 **どの行でsignal SIGABRTが発生しているのか**,  **全ての`@IBOutlet`は確実に接続されて非nilの状態になっているのか** 、くらいは確認して、ご質問内容を編集して追記してください。

Answer (score 0):

提示いただいたコードに、問題点はありません。検証用に作成したiOSのプロジェクトに、そのまま記述しても、クラッシュすることなく、イメージの受け渡しができています。

「signal SIGABRT」というエラーは、もっとも頻出度の高いエラーですが、「コード上は、とくに問題になる箇所が見つからない」というとき、Storyboard上の編集の不備が原因であることが、よくあります。Connectionが正しいか、実体のないConnectionが残っていないかを、徹底的にチェックしてください。Connectionを張った後に、`View`の名称を変えたりすると、編集の不備となることがあります。